# Flutter Host Web App: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

like many I am struggling with hosting my flutter app with firebase, however, none of the solutions found online helped.

The App **runs fine locally** in the Browser, but when hosted it shows a blank page. Inside the Dev tools I get the following error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been
> created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
> at Object.u [as app] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:114)

My **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="communitree">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>...</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script type="module">
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

    const firebaseConfig = {...};

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Initialize Firebase
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
     });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Part of my **main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
firebase_auth: ^3.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^2.1.0
cloud_functions: ^3.0.5
firebase_core: ^1.1.1
```

Thank you for any help or ideas what might be the issue!

Comment: How are you deploying the app? Are you using flutter build web? Then what folder did you choose for your public folder? It should be /build/web.

Comment: Yes to both. For firebase init I use:
public directory: "build/web"
then the option build as SPA: "y"

Afterwords I build the app with "flutter build web", then deploy with "firebase deploy --only hosting". There are no errors. Just in the console of the browser and I only get a blank page

Comment: Probably check your credentials that theu are right.

Comment: You mean the config file? I have and it's okay. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps try adding firebase_core_web as a dependency as well?